# Is there a programming language where a variable is evaluated when it is accessed?

Tags: programming-languages

The below is the pseudo-code of what I want to explain, in JavaScript-like syntax.

```js
const func1 = (x => x * x); // JavaScript Arrow Function syntax.
const func2 = (x => {log("I'm func2!"); return x + 1;});

var a;
var b <= func1(a); // `<=` is a *Binding* operator.
var c <= func2(b);

a = 1;
log(c); // Logs "I'm func2!", and then logs 2, which is ((a * a) + 1).
log(b); // Logs 1, which is (a * a).

a = 2;
log(c); // Logs "I'm func2!", and then logs 5, which is ((a * a) + 1).
log(b); // Logs 4, which is (a * a).

// When b or c is accessed, the function for it is called and make the value.
```

Is there a programming language that has the concept explained above?

Comment: You may want to have a look at functional languages like Haskell (which is one of the 'purest' functional languages)

Comment: Lazy evaluation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation

Comment: Excel spreadsheets kind of work like this.

Comment: @DAXaholic nope, I believe lexical scoping spoils what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The main evaluation strategies in programming languages are *lazy* (for example, call-by-name) and *strict* (for example, call-by-value). Lazy languages evaluate an expression only when it is needed; strict languages evaluate an expression eagerly. To be concrete, the difference usually arises in function calls: lazy languages pass the argument to the function unevaluated, and strict languages evaluate the argument and then call the function. There are lots of tradeoffs that you can read about, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy.

But your code example raises a question: how does the binding to b work? Regardless of whether the language is strict or lazy, you have a problem because you're going to want to use the value of a, which you haven't bound yet. This brings up a second parameter in programming language design: static versus dynamic scope. In a statically-scoped language, a variable's scope is determined statically. That is, the "a" passed to func1 is exactly the a that is in scope at the time func1 is called. In a dynamically-scoped language, a variable's scope is determined at runtime, so it would be possible to imagine that func1(a) is evaluated lazily, in which case the a in scope at that time is the one after the assignment to a.

The question of static vs. dynamic scope, however, is mostly a resolved one: static scope is almost always the right answer. Some languages tried using dynamic scope (e.g. older LISPs) but switched to static scope because people found it too confusing.

So, in summary, I could imagine a language that works the way you describe, but it's likely that most people would find it very confusing to use.

Comment: It's not so bad -- notice that in [at least most of] lisps, even if they do have lexical scoping, the toplevel definitions are bound dynamically (otherwise you could not redefine them in repl, and would have to use something like letrec or Y combinator to be able to write recursive definitions).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know such language, but I know a different strategy for that: you can wrap the call again in a Lambda object. It would have the same effect as you have described. E.g. in Lisp you can do:

```
(defun some-func (x) (* x x))
(defvar *a* (lambda () (some-func 4)))
*a* ;; => returns the function
(*a*) ;; => returns 16
```

That is possible in almost all today's languages. Even in C, but there it's getting pretty hard.

Comment: this allows to pospone evaluation of value, but does it allow to alter it?

Comment: If you consider changing the used lambda as "altering" it, then it is possible: `(setf *a* (lambda () (some-func 10))`

Answer (score 0):

What a funny coincidence! I happen to be aware of one language which has this property, it exists since Monday, here: https://github.com/drcz/ZJEB

It was supposed to be partly a joke and partly an experiment in expressiveness; here is a REPL session with your example:

```
(-- ALGORITHMIC LANGUAGE ZJEB v0.1 --)
 copyleft 2016/08/08 by Scislav Dercz
type (halt) to quit

READY.
>(def func1 (bind (x) (* x x)))
(new shorthand func1 memoized)
>(def func2 (bind (x) (+ x 1)))
(new shorthand func2 memoized)
>(def a 1)
(new shorthand a memoized)
>(def b (func1 a))
(new shorthand b memoized)
>(def c (func2 b))
(new shorthand c memoized)
>c
2
>b
1
>(def a 2)
(new shorthand a memoized)
>c
5
>b
4
```

and here's a simpler one

```
>(def x 5)
(new shorthand x memoized)
>(def y (* x x))
(new shorthand y memoized)
>y
25
>(def x 3)
(new shorthand x memoized)
>y
9
```

The thing is, unlike in scheme (or any other lisp I know), the "def" form does not evaluate the second operand -- it just creates a syntactical "shorthand" to an expression given. So any time the evaluator finds a symbol, it tries to look it up in the environment (i.e. variable-value bindings created with "bind" form -- which is a multi-case pattern-matching variant of "lambda" form from lisp), and if it fails, it also check the list of definitions -- when it succeeds, it immediately evaluates the coresponding expression.

It was not meant to do things which you describe (and in general is not usefull at all, only forcing the evaluator to do a little more work in the current implementation), as the language is purely functional (and actually the only reason re-defining a shorthand is possible is for the convenience of working with repl). This "feature" is in there because I wanted to think about recursive definitions like

```
(def fact (bind (0) 1
                (n) (* n (fact (- n 1)))))
```

to actually mean an infinite expression

```
(bind (0) 1
      (n) (* n ((bind (0) 1
                      (n) (* n ...)) (- n 1)))
```

in the spirit of Dana Scott's "Lattice of flow diagrams".

Note that infinite data structures like

```
(def evil `(ha ,evil))
```

do break the interpreter when you try to evaluate them, though I should probably make them legit [by means of partly-lazy evaluation or something] as well...

Back to your question, you might take a look at various Functional Reactive Programming languages/frameworks, as they provide the behaviors you ask for, at least for certain datatypes.

Svik's comment is also very nice, spreadsheet formulas work this way (and some people claim them to be an FRP language).

*(The lazy evaluation thing is rather not the case, because variable scope in any "lazy" language I happen to know is lexical -- laziness+dynamic scoping would probaly be too confusing, as mcoblenz stated above).*

Answer (score 0):

Lazy evaluation is a method to evaluate a Haskell program. It means that expressions are not evaluated when they are bound to variables, but their evaluation is deferred until their results are needed by other computations.
https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_evaluation

Answer (score 0):

What you need is call-by-name and mutable variables. One of the earliest languages with (optional) call-by-name was [Algol 60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_60).

A more modern language with (optional) call-by-name is [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org). Here is a port your sample code to Scala:

```
def log(a: Any) = println(a)

def func1(x: => Int) = x * x
def func2(x: => Int) = {
  log("I'm func2!")
  x + 1
}

var a = 0

def rest1(b: => Int) = {
  def rest2(c: => Int) = {
    a = 1
    log(c); // Logs "I'm func2!", and then logs 2, which is ((a * a) + 1).
    log(b); // Logs 1, which is (a * a).

    a = 2;
    log(c); // Logs "I'm func2!", and then logs 5, which is ((a * a) + 1).
    log(b); // Logs 4, which is (a * a).
  }
  rest2(func2(b))
}
rest1(func1(a))
```

Parameters that are declared such as `b: => Int` are call-by-name (whereas `b: Int` would be call-by-value).